# An expression for the Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider a general $n$th order linear equation
>   $$x^{n}(t)+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}(t)+ \dots + a_{1}x'(t) + a_{0}x(t).$$
>   Let $x_1, x_2 , \dots , x_n$ be a fundamental set of solutions of above and set $W(t)=W(x_1, x_2 , \dots , x_n ; t).$

How to show that $W(t)=W(t_0) e^{-\int_{t_0}^{t} a_{n-1}(s)~ds}.$

So we know that since $x_1, x_2 , \dots , x_n$ form a fundamental set of solutions, the set of vectors $\{ x_1, x_2 , \dots , x_n \}$ are linearly independent. This implies $W(t)=W(x_1, x_2 , \dots , x_n ; t) \neq 0$ for any $t \in (-\infty, \infty).$ This is all I've got. I need help in solving this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

You need to show that

$$\frac{dW(t)}{dt}=-a_{n-1}(t)W(t),$$
using the expression of 
$$W(t)=\det\begin{pmatrix}x_1&\cdots&x_n\\&\cdots&\\x_1^{(n-1)}&\cdots&x_n^{(n-1)}\end{pmatrix}$$

The key step is to show that 
$$W'(t)=\det\begin{pmatrix}x_1&\cdots&x_n\\&\cdots&\\x_1^{(n-2)}&\cdots&x_n^{(n-2)}\\x_1^{(n)}&\cdots&x_n^{(n)}\end{pmatrix}.$$

To see this, you need to express $W(t)$ as
$$\sum_{\sigma} \text{sign}(\sigma)x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)}'\cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{(n-1)},$$
where $\sigma$ is a permutation of $1,\dots, n$ and this sum is over all permutations.

See http://hobbes.la.asu.edu/courses/site/442/dets.pdf for some explanations of writing determinants using permutations.

Now using product rule to find the derivative.

$$W'(t)=\sum_{\sigma} \text{sign}(\sigma)x'_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)}'\cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{(n-1)}+\sum_{\sigma} \text{sign}(\sigma)x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)}''x''_{\sigma(3)}\cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{(n-1)}+\sum_{\sigma} \text{sign}(\sigma)x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)}'\cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{(n)}$$
In the above formula, you can see that each term is again the determinant of a matrix, all of which except the last one contain two identical rows. For example, the first term is the determinant of the matrix with the first row of $W(t)$ replaced by $(x_1'x_2'\cdots x_n')$, hence the first two rows are identical. So all terms are zero except the one containing the $n$-th derivative.

By the original ODE, we have
$$W'(t)=W'(t)=\det\begin{pmatrix}x_1&\cdots&x_n\\&\cdots&\\x_1^{(n-2)}&\cdots&x_n^{(n-2)}\\-a_{n-1}x_1^{(n-1)}-\cdots-a_0x_1&\cdots&-a_{n-1}x_n^{(n-1)}-\cdots-a_0x_n\end{pmatrix}.$$

By the properties of determinants, adding a multiple of one row to another does not change the determinant, so we perform
$$a_0R_1+R_n\rightarrow R_n, \dots, a_{n-2}R_{n-1}+R_n\rightarrow R_n,$$
where $R_i$ is the $i$-th row of $W'(t)$. This gives us
$$W'(t)=\det\begin{pmatrix}x_1&\cdots&x_n\\&\cdots&\\x_1^{(n-2)}&\cdots&x_n^{(n-2)}\\-a_{n-1}x_1^{(n-1)}&\cdots&-a_{n-1}x_n^{(n-1)}\end{pmatrix}.$$
Hence 
$$W'(t)=-a_{n-1}W(t).$$
Now solving this ODE will give you the result.

Comment: Thank you. I know how to prove the usual Wronskian formula:
$$W(t)=W(t_0) \exp \left(  \int_{t_0}^{t} \text{tr}(A(s)) \right),$$
using a typical Taylor series argument. But still don't know how to prove the one required.

Comment: @Fib1123: What is $A(s)$? If $\tr(A)=r_1+\cdots+r_n$, where $r_i$ are the solutions of the characteristic equation, then $\tr(A)$ is exactly $-a_{n-1}$.

Comment: The coefficient matrix evaluated at $s.$ i.e., when the system of equations is given in terms of $x'(t)=A(t) x(t).$

Comment: @Fib1123: Isn't $\text{tr}(A)$ exactly $-a_{n-1}(t)$?

Comment: It gotta be. But I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: @Fib1123: I am not sure where you got stuck. You say you know how to prove $W(t)=W(t_0) \exp \left(  \int_{t_0}^{t} \text{tr}(A(s)) \right)$. And the problem asks you to show $W(t)=W(t_0) e^{-\int_{t_0}^{t} a_{n-1}(s)~ds}$. Now writing $y_1=x, y_2=x',\dots,y_n=x^{n-1}$, you get the system $y_1'=y_2,\dots, y_{n-1}'=y_n, y_n'=-a_0y_1-\cdots-a_{n-1}y_{n}$. This gives you the coefficient matrix $A$ that has trace $-a_{n-1}$.

Comment: That would prove it. (Although I am not sure how to prove $W(t)=W(t_0) \exp \left(  \int_{t_0}^{t} \text{tr}(A(s)) \right)$ using Taylor series.) The determinant method in my answer would work too.

Comment: I know how to do the problem by writing the equivalent first order system. I thought I have to provide an independent proof without using the expression I wrote above. And to get that you basically start from $X(t)=X(t_0)+(t-t_0) X'(t_0)+o(t-t_0),$ and take the determinant and use the definition of the derivative.

Comment: @Fib1123: I see. I think either method is fine. If you don't think so, try the method in my answer then. Let me know where you didn't understand.

Comment: I haven't seen an argument like yours before, specially writing the Wronskian in terms of permutations.

Comment: @Fib1123: I have edited to give some details. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanatory answer. I'll go through this. May be you too agree that the Taylor series method is much shorter.

Comment: @Fib1123: It looks like so :) although I haven't tried. Since the problem didn't specify the method, I think you can use either one. By the way, knowing the determinant can be written using permutations is very useful in many aspects.